# How to display LanguageTool suggestions with neovim

Tags: neovim, filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex

I want to see LanguageTool suggestions (not just errors) when using LanguageTool with my LaTeX documents. LanguageTool can output the `Error`, `Context`, and `Suggestion`. However, with my setup (`ltex-ls` and `vimtex`) I only see the `Error`.

I use the plugins `ltex-ls` and `vimtex` which are nice because they check the documents on save. The `vim-grammarous` plugin is nice because it also shows the `Suggestions`, as can be seen by the animation on their [github page](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-grammarous/tree/master). However, I would prefer if I didn't have to run `:GrammarousCheck` each time. **Is it instead possible to configure the plugins `ltex-ls` and `vimtex` to show the suggestions?**